# Issue with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in mvc

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-insert

I have following query written in my c# class.

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO UserPersonalInfo(col1,col2,col3)
                VALUES (@c1,@c2,@c3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2 = @c2, col3= @c3";
query += " SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
```

But I am getting following error while running above query,

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.

Comment: You are mixing SQL Server and MySQL constructs.  What database are you really using?

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: i am using sql server, (sql server 2008 r2)

Comment: Sql server option for this is `MERGE` https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MERGE` , demo

```
DECLARE @ui TABLE(
    col1 INT PRIMARY KEY,
    col2 INT 
    )

INSERT INTO @ui(col1,col2) 
VALUES (1,100), (2,200);

-- parameters
DECLARE  @c1 INT = 1,  @c2 INT = 300;

MERGE @ui AS T
USING (
    VALUES (@c1,  @c2)
) AS S(col1,col2)
ON (T.col1 = S.col1)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT(col1,col2) VALUES(S.col1,S.col2)
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET T.col2 = S.col2;

SELECT * 
FROM @ui
```

Assuming `col1` is PK, in your c# code just replace `string query = ...` with

```
string query = @"MERGE UserPersonalInfo AS T
USING (
    VALUES (@c1,@c2,@c3)
) AS S(col1,col2,col3)
ON (T.col1 = S.col1)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT(col1,col2, col3) VALUES(S.col1,S.col2, S.col3)
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET T.col2 = S.col2, T.col3 = S.col3";
```

Comment: how can i write this in the form of string? as i am running query from c#.

Comment: i just wrote the same string :p bdw its working :) but first let me do some testing for the same :D unable to upvote due to my less reputation :(

Comment: You may wish to accept the answer to show others this is correct.